Can I convert mesh (generated by script) to FBX file (or someting else that is compatible with blender). Unity
I have an island that is procedurally generated in unity using a script, and it would be good if I could somehow export the island I like and put it into blender. I need to model structures that will be suitable for the island.
I have no idea how to do this.
Thanks for any help

In the Unity editor, go up to the top menu bar (file, edit, asset, ect...). From Window drop down to PackageManager. Open it. In the package manager go to the upper left of the window there is a  tab that starts with packages:and a name is in this field. Click it to drop down some options. Select Unity Registry to access all of the modules and add-ons Unity includes for free. In the search bar, type FBX Exporter. Download it and read the API. You should have no problem exporting your meshes.

It'd be helpful if you could provide more details! Is the generated mesh only in runtime (as in you only see it when you hit play)? Or is it a GameObject in the scene?

If it's in the scene, you could use a Unity package to convert to FBX, as the other answer suggested. You could also follow this thread (https://discussions.unity.com/t/export-unity-mesh-to-obj-or-fbx-format/525773). It's a little old, but I believe it should help!
If it's in runtime, I think these plugins could work! (Convert mesh to stl/obj/fbx in runtime)


It's generated in runtime, and the FBX exporter works
